# Filtrar DataGridView C# MySql

Tags: mysql, c#

Buenas tengo un form con un datagridview cargado con datos de mysql con este codigo

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string cadenaConexion = "Database=cobranza; Data source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; SSL Mode=None;";

        MySqlConnection conexionDB;
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataReader resultado;

        try
        {
            conexionDB = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM clientestotal;", conexionDB);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            conexionDB.Open();

            resultado = comando.ExecuteReader();

            dataTable.Load(resultado);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
```

Y estoy buscando como poder filtrar los datos de esta tabla con un textbox poder buscar ya sea por cliente rut o factura

[image: Asi se ve al ejecutar]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola buenas tardes amigo, considero que deberías de crear un método para cargar los datos, una vez cargado puedes realizar el filtrado en el grid, te lo menciono porque estas cargando los datos con el evento

> dataGridView1_CellContentClick

el cuál se ejecuta cada vez que das clic sobre el contenido del grid.

Puedes crear el método y luego llamarlo cuando necesites actualizar datos del grid.

```
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    private void GetData()
    {
        string cadenaConexion = "Database=cobranza; Data source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; SSL Mode=None;";

        MySqlConnection conexionDB;
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataReader resultado;

        try
        {
            conexionDB = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM clientestotal;", conexionDB);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            conexionDB.Open();

            resultado = comando.ExecuteReader();

            dataTable.Load(resultado);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        bs.DataSource = dataTable;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

El siguiente código realiza el filtro al bindingsource enlazado al grid

```
void FilterData()
    {
        try
        {
            if (bs.DataSource != null)
            {
                bs.Filter = $" factura LIKE '%{textbox1.Text}%'";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Filtrando datos...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Ahora en el evento TextChanged del textbox realizas lo siguiente, para que cada vez que digites en el textbox se realice el filtro

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FilterData();
    }
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.
Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvio! para poder filtrar por mas opciones tendria que cambiar la consulta $" factura LIKE '%{txtBuscar.Text}%'"; ?

Comment: Así es amigo, tienes que cambiar la consulta, por ejemplo si deseas filtrar por varios campos y utilizar un solo textbox lo puedes hacer de esta manera: $"factura LIKE '%{txtBuscar.Text}%' OR cliente  LIKE '%{txtBuscar.Text}%'"

Comment: Y si deseas Filtrar con varios campos con sus respectivos textbox lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera: $"factura LIKE '%{txtBuscarFactura.Text}%' AND cliente LIKE '%{txtBuscarCliente.Text}%'  "